# Why and how do I change my buttons style, my the other compose button is fine?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I've changed my navigation bar style to black opaque but my done button remains blue, yet the compose button is fine / black.

Why is is happening and more importantanly how do I fix this ?

The buttons was added in IB and shows blue there, while the nav bar is black.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to make sure you're using the UIBarButtonSystemItemDone system button item, unaltered.  If you really want to change the appearance of your Done button, you will need to assign a custom view to the bar button item's customView property.  Then you'll be able to control every aspect of its appearance.

Comment: I'm currently using UIBarButtonSystemItemDone which shows the button blue no matter if I use black style or not. Do you mean I'd have to use a normal buttons and add the text 'Done' ? I'm not sure what you mean custom view property ??

Comment: UIBarButtonItem has a property called customView.  You can create your own UIView and assign it to the customView property of your UIBarButtonItem, and it'll display your custom view instead of the regular Done button.  This means that, even though Apple doesn't allow you to modify the look of the default Done button, you can make your bar button item look any way you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what this would achieve, what would I add to my custom UIView ? isn't this just a step further than having a custom button, or have I missed the point ?? thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to describe: using a custom button for your Done button.  Since there isn't support for modifying the default Done button, you'll have to make your own and use that as the view for your UIBarButtonItem.